# How to set SSLContext options in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ssl, openssl

I need to create an `SSLSocket` in Ruby 1.8+ to talk to an encrypted service. I want to set SSL options on the `SSLContext` object (it eventually calls `SSL_CTX_set_options` in the underlying OpenSSL library). I am not seeing any obvious way to do this.

This is using the `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext` interface.

As a point of reference, this is analogous to calling the [`set_options()`](http://packages.python.org/pyOpenSSL/openssl-context.html) in Python's pyOpenSSL library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example:

```
ctx = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new

ctx.set_params(:options => OpenSSL::SSL::OP_EPHEMERAL_RSA | OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_SSLv2)
# or
ctx.options = OpenSSL::SSL::OP_EPHEMERAL_RSA | OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_SSLv2
```

Comment: Nice example. It beats the snot out of what the Ruby docs are providing. How do you attach the context to an `http` when `http.use_ssl = true`?

Comment: @jww: Seems like there's no API for that yet: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9450 *sigh*

Answer (score 1):

If you need to set `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext` options before request you can do it in this way:

```rb
    # Set options that you need
    OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::DEFAULT_PARAMS[:options] |= OpenSSL::SSL::OP_LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT

    # Make a request
    uri = URI('https://example.com')
    res = Net::HTTP.post(uri, {}.to_json)

    # Unset options
    OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::DEFAULT_PARAMS[:options] &= ~OpenSSL::SSL::OP_LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT
```