# How to set TLS context options in Ruby (like OpenSSL::SSL::SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2)

Tags: ruby, ssl, openssl

When using OpenSSL in C, we set options on the context to remove weak and wounded protocols like SSLv2 and SSLv3. From `ssl.h`, here is a bitmask of some of the options that are useful:

```c
#define SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2     0x01000000L
#define SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3     0x02000000L
#define SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1     0x04000000L
#define SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_2   0x08000000L
#define SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1   0x10000000L
```

However, I'm having trouble setting them in Ruby:

```ruby
if uri.scheme == "https"
  http.use_ssl = true
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
  http.options = OpenSSL::SSL::SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_SSLv3 |
                 OpenSSL::SSL::SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION
end
```

Results in:

```bash
$ ./TestCert.rb
./TestCert.rb:12:in `<main>': uninitialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::SSL_OP_SSL2 (NameError)
```

The [Ruby docs for 1.9.3](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL.html) (and 2.0.0) don't even bother to mention it.

How does one set the TLS context options in Ruby?

---

Related: [setting SSLContext options in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3818232/608639). But there's no way to attach the context to an `http` when `http.use_ssl = true`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the Ruby OpenSSL library the option constants aren't prefixed with 'SSL_'. You can see a list of the option constants by running something like this in irb/console: `OpenSSL::SSL.constants.grep(/OP_/)`. Here is the relevant ruby C source where they are defined: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/ext/openssl/ossl_ssl.c#L2225.

**Edit:** 
There doesn't appear to be a way, out of the box, to set the SSL options for net http.
See https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9450.

However for the time being you can use this little hack:

```
(Net::HTTP::SSL_IVNAMES << :@ssl_options).uniq!
(Net::HTTP::SSL_ATTRIBUTES << :options).uniq!

Net::HTTP.class_eval do
  attr_accessor :ssl_options
end
```

Now just set the ssl_options accessor on the instance of Net::HTTP. Example usage:

```
uri = URI('https://google.com:443')

options_mask = OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_SSLv2 + OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_SSLv3 +
  OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_COMPRESSION

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)

if uri.scheme == "https"
  http.use_ssl = true
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
  http.ssl_options = options_mask
end

response = http.request request

# To Test
ssl_context = http.instance_variable_get(:@ssl_context)
ssl_context.options == options_mask # => true
```

I was testing with ruby 2.1.2 so your mileage on other versions of ruby may vary. Let me know if it doesn't work on your preferred version.

For those interested, the relevant part of the ruby code I looked at to create this hack: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/e9dce8d1b482200685996f64cc2c3bd6ba790110/lib/net/http.rb#L886

Comment: Nice, thanks Gray. A related question for Ruby 1.8.7 on OS X 10.8. It looks like `SSLv2` and `SSLv3` are OK; however: `uninitialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_COMPRESSION` and `uninitialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_COMP`. A mistake on my part? Or is this more Apple insecurity?

Comment: This gets eve worse for me... `http.options` results int `undefined method 'options=' for #<Net::HTTP example.com:8443 open=false>`.

Comment: @jww make sure you include the first code block. That is what's responsible for adding the `ssl_options=` method.

Comment: to be able to compile Ruby 1.8.7 you need to patch it beforehand: https://gist.github.com/hyoshida/11241844