# Ruby OpenSSL, print issuer and subject of pem file

Tags: ruby, ssl, openssl

How do I print (or save to variable) the Issuer and Subject from a .pem certificate using the OpenSSL module ?

(This is after trying to understand the [ruby-docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/X509/Certificate.html))

Comment: In pure C with OpenSSL, we would use `X509_NAME* iname = X509_get_issuer_name(cert)` and `X509_NAME* sname = X509_get_subject_name(cert)`, where `cert` is an `X509*`. We would then use `X509_NAME_get_index_by_NID`, `X509_NAME_get_entry`, `X509_NAME_ENTRY_get_data` and finally `ASN1_STRING_to_UTF8` to drill into a `char*` to print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this System-depended and ugly code, but I'm sure there is a much nicer thing to do

```
pfxsubject = %x(openssl x509 -in '/root/cert.pem' -noout -subject | cut -c 10-).to_s.chomp
```

Comment: "I'm sure there is a much nicer thing to do..." - Ruby is pretty lame in what it exposes from OpenSSL. There's no way to do a lot of useful things, like disabling SSLv2 and disabling compression. See, for example, [uninitialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::SSL_OP_SSLv2 (NameError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22550213/uninitialized-constant-opensslsslssl-op-sslv2-nameerror).