# SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A: wrong version number (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)

Tags: ruby, ssl

When I ran `https.ssl_version = :TLSv1_2`

I got the error

```
ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:920:in `connect': 
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A: 
wrong version number (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

Whe I changed to `https.ssl_version = :SSLv3`

```
ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:920:in `connect': 
SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A 
(OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

But I can do it without any error by rest client

```
resp = RestClient.post(server_url, content, header)
```

The ssl connection is make me confused so much.

The problem both on macos and ubuntu 14.04

### UPDATE

Check my SSL parameters

### Under default Ruby by `irb`

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'openssl'
=> true
irb(main):002:0>  OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::DEFAULT_PARAMS
=> {:ssl_version=>"SSLv23", :verify_mode=>1, :ciphers=>"ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW", :options=>-2147482625}
```

### Under Rails

```
{
    :ssl_version => "SSLv23",
    :verify_mode => 1,
        :ciphers => "ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW",
        :options => -2147482625
}
#<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A>
```

### Brute force to try all kind of SSL version within Rails

```
I changed the method by `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::DEFAULT_PARAMS[:ssl_version]=method`

:TLSv1
#<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A>
:TLSv1_server
#<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A>
:TLSv1_client
#<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A>
:TLSv1_2
#<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A>
:TLSv1_2_server
#<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A>
:TLSv1_2_client
#<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A>
:TLSv1_1
#<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A>
:TLSv1_1_server
#<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A>
:TLSv1_1_client
#<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A>
:SSLv3
#<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A>
:SSLv3_server
#<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A>
:SSLv3_client
#<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A>
:SSLv23
#<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A>
:SSLv23_server
#<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A>
:SSLv23_client
#<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A>
:TLSv1
#<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A>
:TLSv1_server
#<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A>
:TLSv1_client
#<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A>
:TLSv1_2
#<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A>
:TLSv1_2_server
#<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A>
:TLSv1_2_client
#<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A>
:TLSv1_1
#<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A>
:TLSv1_1_server
#<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A>
:TLSv1_1_client
#<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A>
:SSLv3
#<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A>
:SSLv3_server
#<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A>
:SSLv3_client
#<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A>
:SSLv23
#<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A>
:SSLv23_server
#<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A>
:SSLv23_client
#<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A>
```

Comment: same problem here. did you solve this?

Comment: please check the port number and address.

Answer (score 6):

If you set the `ssl_version` to `TLSv1_2` and the server does not support that version then you will see this error (same for `SSLv3`).

My guess is that RestClient probably just uses Ruby's default `SSLv23`. If that version is supported by the server it might just work.

Check the default for your Ruby version like this:

```
require 'openssl'
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::DEFAULT_PARAMS
# => {
# =>     :ssl_version => "SSLv23",
# =>     :verify_mode => 1,
# =>     :ciphers     => "ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW",
# =>     :options     => -2147482625
# => }
```

If `https.ssl_version = :TLSv1_2` does not work then I would try other versions.

You can get a list of all available versions in your Ruby with:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::METHODS
```

I would start with:

```
https.ssl_version = 'SSLv23'
```

Or you may want to ask the owner of the server which versions are supported.

Comment: Hi I updated my status, unfortunely, it seems the `DEFAULT_PARAMS ` are identical for the 2 environment

Comment: I tried all the SSL method, but still getting error within Rails , But works outside Rails

Answer (score 4):

```
 When I ran https.ssl_version = :TLSv1_2
 ...
 https.ssl_version = :SSLv3
```

Any peer supporting only TLS1.0 or TLS1.1 will not work with both of these tests, because the offered version is either too high or too low. It is better to leave the default to SSLv23 handshake but explicitly disable SSLv3.

To do this you need to fiddle with the options and add `SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24237525/3081018

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I'm in an Airbnb with some suspect wifi and started getting this error. I think it was some overly "helpful" firewall (or something like that) in the router. I installed Cloudflare WARP and my problems are fixed.