# SSLv3 certificate verify failure when TLSv1 was specified?

Tags: ruby, openssl

Can someone help me figure this out. I've seen this asked all over the web, but no one has an adequate answer.

I am on Ubuntu, Ruby 1.8.7, and OpenSSL 1.0.1

```
Net::HTTP.ssl_context_accessor 'ssl_version'
uri = URI.parse("https://www.paypal.com")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
http.use_ssl = true
http.ssl_version = :TLSv1

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)

response = http.request(request)
```

It returns

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

Why is it complaining about SSLv3, if I am specifying TLSv1?

I know it's using TLSv1 because if I did

```
http.ssl_version = :SSLv3
```

It will return

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A: sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

Which is expected.

I am not sure what to make of this error, my `ca-certificates` are up to date.

I can't do any of that fancy `OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_SSLv3` stuff because Ruby 1.8.7 does not support any of those options.

Thanks for your help.

Related and helpful answers, but not the solution

- [How to set TLS context options in Ruby (like OpenSSL::SSL::SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22550213/how-to-set-tls-context-options-in-ruby-like-opensslsslssl-op-no-sslv2)
- [Faraday Throws Error When Setting SSL Version](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/issues/309)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed... 
>   Why is it complaining about SSLv3, if I am specifying TLSv1?

Its an artifact of the error messages in OpenSSL. Don't worry too much about it (other than the take away of "verification failed").

---

You did not ask this question, but here's how to fix it. You should include `ca_file`:

```
Net::HTTP.ssl_context_accessor 'ssl_version'
uri = URI.parse("https://www.paypal.com")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
http.use_ssl = true
http.ssl_version = :TLSv1
http.ca_file = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "ca.pem")
```

`ca.pem` should be a PEM encoded version of VeriSign's *Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority* or *VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5*. You can fetch it from the Symantec's website under [Use of Root Certificates](https://www.symantec.com/page.jsp?id=roots).

---

You can discover the needed CA certificate with the following command. You are *usually* interested in the ***last*** *Issuer* in the chain.

The issuer is the one displayed with the *"i:"*, like *i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority*. The *"s:"* is used for *Subject*, and that's who the certificate was issued to.

```
$ openssl s_client -connect www.paypal.com:443 -tls1 -servername www.paypal.com -showcerts
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = "VeriSign, Inc.", OU = VeriSign Trust Network, OU = "(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", CN = VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/jurisdictionC=US/jurisdictionST=Delaware/businessCategory=Private Organization/serialNumber=3014267/C=US/postalCode=95131-2021/ST=California/L=San Jose/street=2211 N 1st St/O=PayPal, Inc./OU=CDN Support/CN=www.paypal.com
   i:/C=US/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Symantec Trust Network/CN=Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G2
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:/C=US/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Symantec Trust Network/CN=Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G2
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 2 s:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

---

> I am not sure what to make of this error, my ca-certificates are up to date.

*Don't* add the CA Zoo (`ca-certs.pem`). You know the CA that certifies PayPal, so use it. There's no need to bring in an addition 300 or so CAs (299 which are incorrect).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am going to award you the answer because you answered my question about the error, and provided me with information on how to fix my problem. Unfortunately I was not able to fix my problem. There must be a bug in Ruby 1.8.7 and OpenSSL 1.0.1, because I still get that error no matter what cert I use. Something is specifically wrong with Ruby 1.8.7, because it works fine in Ruby 1.9.3+.

Comment: There've been several SSL-related bugs recently, but as I said in my answer, very old Ruby versions like 1.8.7 are not supported any longer. Found bugs are only fixed in still supported versions. The support for 1.8.7 and 1.9.2 was actually extended, but it finally run out in summer 2014. And as I said, the support for 1.9.3 run out some weeks ago, too. So I'd really recommend to update to a current ruby version.

Comment: @Henning - I'm not sure what Ruby versions have to do error messages and using `http.ca_file`. Perhaps you intended to leave this comment somewhere else?

Comment: No, it's meant to be here. As with about any software, bugs in Ruby are found and corrected consistently, some in connection to SSL, some from other areas. But only Ruby versions that are still supported are fixed. As @vinhboy said, the problem appears with 1.8.7, but not with 1.9.3+. So it's highly probable that it's a bug that's been fixed in 1.9.3, but not in 1.8.7, because that fell out of support before. And 1.9.3 is "finished" as well, so vinhboy might run into a similar situation with another problem. Because of that (and generally in most cases), it's advisable to use current software.

Comment: @Henning - Perhaps you should leave this comment with the fellow who asked the question. The comments have nothing to do with an answer instructing to use `ca_file` to supply the CA that certified the end-entity certificate.

Comment: My comment was in reference to vinhboy's comment to you answer. But I see your point.

Answer (score 3):

So as I said in the comments, this is most likely a bug that affects Ruby 1.8.7 and OpenSSL 1.0.1 - When you try to connect to a server that has SSLv3 disabled using TLSv1, it will return a `certificate verify failed` error.

After a lot of searching around, here is what I did

```
http.instance_eval { 
  @ssl_context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new 
  @ssl_context.set_params({:options=>OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_SSLv3})
}
```

This hack allows you to set the `OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_SSLv3` option, which fixes the problem.

Thanks to a tip from https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/200072

Comment: That is kind of interesting. The fix you describe is usually for the *"Unsupported Protocol"* error message; and not the *"Verification Failed"* error message you described in the question. Are you certain about this?

Comment: Yea. I booted up an instance on aws and installed just Ruby 1.8. Ubuntu has OpenSSL 1.0.1  by default. From irb, using the sample code above, I consistently get `certificate verify failed`. The error goes away when I switch to Ruby 1.9. This little patch fixes it for 1.8 though.

Answer (score 1):

Probably Ruby can't find any trustworthy root certificates, see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528101/ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-sslv3-read-server-certificate-b-certificat), among others. Your ruby version is *really* old, I'd assume your certificate bundle is, too. You should update. Some weeks ago the support for Ruby 1.9.3 ended, let alone support for Ruby 1.8.7. The current version is Ruby 2.2.2. There won't be any fixes for versions that old anymore.