# Ruby SSL Error when trying to crawl website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, openssl, rubygems

So, basically im trying to run this script https://github.com/JeffreyATW/mbfc_crawler and it gives me ***this error:***

```
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:933:in `connect_nonblock': SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:933:in `connect'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:858:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-http-persistent-2.9.4/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:700:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-http-persistent-2.9.4/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:631:in `connection_for'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-http-persistent-2.9.4/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:994:in `request'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.5/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:274:in `fetch'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.5/lib/mechanize.rb:464:in `get'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/wombat-2.5.1/lib/wombat/processing/parser.rb:61:in `public_send'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/wombat-2.5.1/lib/wombat/processing/parser.rb:61:in `parser_for'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/wombat-2.5.1/lib/wombat/processing/parser.rb:44:in `parse'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/wombat-2.5.1/lib/wombat/crawler.rb:30:in `crawl'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/wombat-2.5.1/lib/wombat.rb:13:in `crawl'
    from crawler.rb:21:in `block in <main>'
    from crawler.rb:20:in `each'
```

I have installed Ruby 2.3.3 from [Ruby Installer for Windows](https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/).

I have also installed the DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx.exe for my machine(from the same site).

What am i doing wrong? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Use TLS 1.0 and [Server Name Indication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). Also see [How to set SSLContext options in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3818232) and [How to set TLS context options in Ruby (like OpenSSL::SSL::SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22550213). I've become so frustrated in doing simple Security 101 things in Ruby I no longer use it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it needs a CA certificate.

Save it in your m/c from here: https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

And set path of it by using below command:

```
setx SSL_CERT_FILE path_where_you_have_placed_above_file
```

Comment: Well, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Stop using SSLv3, and start using TLS 1.0 (or above) and [Server Name Indication (SNI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication).

Here's what you are doing with Ruby:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect github.com:443 -ssl3
CONNECTED(00000003)
3069617360:error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1275:SSL alert number 40
3069617360:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:598:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
...
```

Here's what you should be doing with Ruby. Notice TLS 1.0 and SNI:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect github.com:443 -tls1 -servername github.com
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/businessCategory=Private Organization/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=US/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=Delaware/serialNumber=5157550/street=88 Colin P Kelly, Jr Street/postalCode=94107/C=US/ST=California/L=San Francisco/O=GitHub, Inc./CN=github.com
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
 1 s:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/businessCategory=Private Organization/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=US/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=Delaware/serialNumber=5157550/street=88 Colin P Kelly, Jr Street/postalCode=94107/C=US/ST=California/L=San Francisco/O=GitHub, Inc./CN=github.com
issuer=/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 3652 bytes and written 384 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
    Session-ID: DD4041221B8CA5DAE8275F48D228A9CF6CE1EB8CCE58208877391CB061E8FE34
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 52979B9BF613EEC54C1F51364C1DA6FF88B9A7D419A66A8216E9A1B0FA0790DEB1B469ADD9AD881B6852913CE607E365
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1485151489
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
```