# How to use TLS 1.2 in Ruby Http client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, openssl, tls1.2

I'm trying to access third party api using TLS 1.2, but getting SSL error event with valid certificates

**Ruby Version:**

```
 ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]
```

**Rails Version:**

```
Rails 4.2.5
```

**CODE:**

```
    ua = Net::HTTP.new(SERVER, 443)
    ua.instance_eval {
      @ssl_context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
      options = OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_SSLv2 | OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_SSLv3
      if OpenSSL::SSL.const_defined?('OP_NO_COMPRESSION')
        options |= OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_COMPRESSION
      end
      @ssl_context.set_params({options: options})
    }
   # ua.instance_eval { @ssl_context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new(:TLSv1_2) }
    ua.use_ssl = true

    # Checks presence of CA certificate
    if File.directory?(RootCA)
      ua.ca_path = RootCA
      ua.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
      ua.verify_depth = 3
    else
      puts "Invalid CA certificates directory. Exiting..."
      exit
    end
```

**ERROR:**

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
    from /home/cp/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:933:in `connect_nonblock'
    from /home/cp/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:933:in `connect'
    from /home/cp/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
    from /home/cp/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
    from /home/cp/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1398:in `request'
    from /home/cp/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1421:in `send_entity'
    from /home/cp/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1209:in `post'
```

Comment: OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new('TLSv1_2_client')

At least that is what I'm using.

Comment: Use TLS 1.0 and [Server Name Indication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). Also see [How to set SSLContext options in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3818232) and [How to set TLS context options in Ruby (like OpenSSL::SSL::SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22550213). I've become so frustrated in doing simple Security 101 things in Ruby I no longer use it.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved after building ruby with  openssl (https://railsfornovice.wordpress.com/2017/03/02/fix-openssl-cert-error-in-rails/)